# R apply function on DF rowwise if condition is met

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, vectorization

Assume the following dataframe and functions:

```
cond    var_x    var_y
cond1       2        3
cond1       3        0.1
cond2       2        2
cond2       1        0.2
```

```
my_fun1 <- function(x) {
  act_vec <- rnorm(500, x, x/4)
  RT = 0
  for (i in 1:length(act_vec)) {
      my_act = act_vec[i]
      my_rt = my_act
      RT = RT + my_rt
  }
  RT = RT/500
  return(RT)
} 
my_fun2 <- function(x,y) {
  act_vec1 <- rnorm(500, x, x/4)
  act_vec2 <- rnorm(500, y, y/4)
  RT = 0
  for (i in 1:length(act_vec1)) {
      my_act1 = act_vec1[i]
      my_act2 = act_vec1[i]*act_vec2[i]
      my_rt = min(my_act1, my_act2)
      RT = RT + my_rt
  }
  RT = RT/500
  return(RT)
}
```

The following code applies the function `my_fun1` to every row in `DF` if `DF$cond == 'cond1'` and otherwise `my_fun2`.

```
my_test_vec = c()
for (i in (1:nrow(DF))) {
  if (DF$cond[i] == 'cond1') {
    my_test = my_fun1(DF$var_x[i])
  } else {
    my_test = my_fun2(DF$var_x[i], DF$var_y[i])
  }
  my_test_vec = c(my_test_vec, my_test)
}
```

This for-loop, however, is computational inefficient. Because of that, I would like to implement it in a way such that all the operations are applied in one go. My approach so far doesn't work and looks like this:

```
DF$results <- ifelse(DF$cond == 'cond1', 
                           my_fun1(DF$var_x), 
                           my_fun2(DF$var_x, DF$var_y))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: ifelse is usually very efficient. If you post sample data and stand ins for myfun 1 and 2 that World help finding your Problem with ifelse.

Comment: I hope the edit is satisfying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should improve your knowledge of the vectorization of R. Below are vectorized versions of your functions. First, the code applies vector arithmetic within the functions. Second, also the whole functions are vectorized; `Vectorize()` makes sure that they can work with vectors as input as it is the case in an`ifelse()`.

```
my_fun1A <- Vectorize(function(x) {
  act_vec <- rnorm(500, x, x/4)
  RT <- sum(act_vec) / 500
  return(RT)
}) 

my_fun2A <- Vectorize(function(x, y) {
  act_vec1 <- rnorm(500, x, x/4)
  act_vec2 <- rnorm(500, y, y/4)
  RT <- sum(pmin(act_vec1, act_vec1*act_vec2)) / 500
  return(RT)
})
```

#### Result

```
set.seed(42)
resA <- ifelse(DF$cond == 'cond1', my_fun1A(DF$var_x), my_fun2A(DF$var_x, DF$var_y))
resA
# [1] 1.9849769 2.9837980 1.9772901 0.2028555
```

#### Comparison with original version

`Vectorize`ing your original versions with the `for` loops inside:

```
my_fun1v <- Vectorize(my_fun1)
my_fun2v <- Vectorize(my_fun2)
set.seed(42)
res <- ifelse(DF$cond == 'cond1', my_fun1v(DF$var_x), my_fun2v(DF$var_x, DF$var_y))
stopifnot(all.equal(res, resA))  ## same result
```

#### Benchmark

```
fun <- function() ifelse(DF$cond == 'cond1', my_fun1v(DF$var_x), my_fun2v(DF$var_x, DF$var_y))
funA <- function() ifelse(DF$cond == 'cond1', my_fun1A(DF$var_x), my_fun2A(DF$var_x, DF$var_y))
set.seed(42)
DF <- DF[sample(1:nrow(DF), 1e4, replace=T), ]

set.seed(42)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fun(), funA(), times=3)
# Unit: seconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  fun() 5.319736 5.352284 5.392068 5.384831 5.428234 5.471636     3   b
# funA() 1.793795 1.793863 1.835880 1.793931 1.856923 1.919914     3  a
```

We can clearly see an improvement of over 60%.

---

*Data:*

```
DF <- read.table(header=T, text="cond    var_x    var_y
cond1       2        3
cond1       3        0.1
cond2       2        2
cond2       1        0.2")
```

Comment: Many, many thanks for this elaborated answer! I did not know the ```Vectorize``` function. And the ```for-loop``` inside the self-defined functions is obsolete, of course. That's something I can do better. Cheers!